# Angularjs - Loading a form from a template without using ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I have a crud application, The situation I want is when you click in the list, the edit form will be opened up in a modal dialog or toggling from the side.

the form is a template (/templates/form.html).

If I use ng-view, everything is simple, I set the templateUrl in the router and I get the form recompiled in the view.

But since I want to still see the grid, I want to open the form above it. so ng-view is not going to work.

how can I do the following from the controller:

1. load the template form maybe via ngInclude remember Im in the JS controller.
2. Bind the model
3. append the form with the binded model to the html

Thanks

Comment: it's not exactly clear from what you are describing why `ng-view` wouldn't work, but generally you don't use `ng-view` for modal dialogs anyway.  If you do need nested routing, however, you might look into a 3rd party alternative like `ui-router`, that supports multiple nested named views.

Comment: @Claies to make it short, I am trying to use ng-include from a controller.

Comment: that doesn't even make sense.  what do you mean, you are trying to use `ng-include` from a controller?  `ng-include` is an HTML level directive, you wouldn't call it from your JavaScript....  You can set the URL for `ng-include` from the controller, and the documentation for `ng-include` has a good example of this.

Comment: @Claies I know, was just trying to explain what is the result I want to achieve.  How do I render a template to a div, regular div. (and bind a model to this template via $scope).

Comment: you still aren't clarifying your actual problem.  if the template is rendered inside an HTML element that has a controller, then the controller still affects that template, even if the template is loaded from a different file.  I think you need to post some sort of [mcve] to clarify what you are trying to do and what isn't working.

Comment: FYI, this sounds like a case where a custom directive might be what you are wanting;  with a custom directive, you can specify a template and a controller in the directive definition.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude ?

Hope it suits your case =)

Comment: ng-include is not dynamic. I need to render the template into a div from a controller